# Configuring websockets using AWS ALB

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to configure Ingress using an AWS ALB. Through this same Ingress, I am able to access every port I choose from my containers but the one for websockets. Here are my configurations:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ****
  name: ****-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ***
  replicas: 3
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: **:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ***
        ...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9944//This is for the Websocket!
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: ****
  name: ***-svc
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: websocket
      targetPort: 9944
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ***
```

And finally the ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ****
  name: ***-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: wstgroup
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=5000
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-timeout: '86400'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: '80'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=600
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn:  ****
  labels:
    app: **
spec:
  rules:
    - host: **.**.cloud
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ws/
            backend:
              serviceName: ***-svc
              servicePort: 80
```

Returns 502 as an error most of the time, with curl, here is the result:

[image]

Thank you!

EDIT: For info, I'm using K8S with Fargate

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?